# Calculate the sum of cross-diagonal elements in a matrix

Tags: math, for-loop, matrix

I want to add together the cross-diagonal elements in a matrix. For example, I have a 3*3 Matrix which is two dimensional, I want to convert it to one dimensional:

```
      -------------------
      |  1  |  2  |  3  |
      -------------------
 A=   |  4  |  5  |  6  |
      -------------------
      |  7  |  8  |  9  |
      -------------------
```

final output will be,

```
     ____ ____ ____ ____ ____
 B= |1   | 6  | 15 | 14 |  9 |
    |____|____|____|____|____|
```

First cross-diagonal `A[0][0]` will be copied to `B[0]`.

Then the next cross-diagonal elements `A[1][0]` and `A[0][1]` will be added and copied to `B[1]`, *i.e.* 4  and 2 will be added.

Then the next cross-diagonal elements `A[2][0]` and `A[1][1]` and `A[0][2]` will be added and copied to `B[2]`, *i.e.* 7, 5 and 3 will be added.

And so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that for each diagonal, the sum of row-index and column-index is equal to the index of B array.  Based on this fact, you can make a algorithm like this:

```
// assuming the width and length of the Matrix is N
// it's good you have some ideas of the range of idea, try figure it out by yourself? 
// definitely it should be a function of N
for (int i=0;i<F(N);i++) { 
  for (int j=0;j<=i;j++) { // consider why j should be in range (0,i) ?
    // some cumulatively add here
  }
}
```

Comment: aw man, this is totally 'homework problem' - you gave the answer away way too easily

Comment: i think in the outer loop, condition should be `<=` instead of `<`

Comment: @Kache ah oh... maybe I should hide some lines of code...

Comment: @Krunal it dependes on whether the index is start from 0 or 1, try it!

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @Krunal for the great question and @POPOL for answer, was keen to see how it would work so created the following 'work in progress': [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/am_d/K6eBC/).

I'm going to look at just what's needed in the loop so that I can eliminate the try routine that flags out of range.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = [   [1,2,3],
                    [4,5,6],
                    [7,8,9],
                    [10,11,12],
                    [13,14,15]
                    ];
        var b = [],N = 4; 
        var item;
        for (i=0;i<2*N-1;i++) {
          b[i] = 0;
          for (j=0;j<=i;j++) {
            try {
                item  = (a[j][i-j] !== undefined)?a[j][i-j]:0;
            }catch(e) {
                console.log("out of range");
                item  =0;
            }
            b[i] +=item;
          }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        for (w=0;w<b.length-1;w++) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML+=b[w] +",";
        } 
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML+=b[b.length-1] ;
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to consider:

- What is the length of array B, in terms of N, generated from the diagonals of an N x N matrix A? Let's refer to that length as L.
- Just to reinforce the point, how is L related to A? This directly related to the outer loop.
- How are the positions of the addends of each element in B related to each other? i.e. They're "diagonal" to each other, but how would you express that mathematically?
- If you can express that mathematically, how would you iterate between them in order to find their sum? This will help you with the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a two-line solution that does not use for loops:

```
x=rbind(matrix(0, nc=ncol(A), nr=ncol(A)-1), A, matrix(0, nc=ncol(A), nr=ncol(A)-1))  
laply(seq(sum(dim(A))-1), function(l) sum(diag(t(x[, ncol(A):1])[, l:nrow(x)])))
```

`[1]  1  6 15 14  9`

The `laply()` function is part of the plyr package.