# Summing EVERY individual diagonal in a 2D array java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I am having trouble with part of my homework assignment. Essentially, what we have to do is take a 2D array full of random numbers and sum each row, column, and diagonal. I have figured out the rows and columns, but cannot get the diagonals. Here is my code pertaining to the diagonals:

```
for (int c = 0 ; c < columnCount; c++)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = (7 - c); i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        sum += board[(7 - c) - i][i];
    }

   return sum;
}
```

I have gotten some of the diagonals summed, but cannot figure out how to get the rest. For instance:

```
_ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 X X X X X X X X
1 X X X X X X X
2 X X X X X X 
3 X X X X X
4 X X X X
5 X X X
6 X X
7 X
```

As you can see, I have only summed half of the board (it is going from top right to bottom left each time). I will eventually need to sum the diagonals in the opposite direction as well...if anyone has insight on that.

I have already looked around on here and on other websites, but the only thing I can find is how to sum the MAJOR diagonals. I need to sum every single diagonal on an 8X8 board. I have really thought through this but no matter what I try I cannot get the other values without going out of bounds. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you please make sure your code snippet is accurate? I corrected the indentation and it appears you may be missing an intended `{` after the `for` loop.

Comment: After 20secs on google:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395022/calculate-the-sum-of-cross-diagonal-elements-in-a-matrix

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of options to do this. Based on the method you are currently using (and trying to be consistent with it), I'd suggest following it up by going from rows 1-7 and completing the missing summations (hint: for remaining items, start at right edge and move down-and-left).

The question that pmkrefeld linked to in the comments contains code to do it (well, hypothetically, I didn't look at it and have no idea if it actually works). The answer there was just given away. It is working code but you will learn more by trying to implement it yourself.

Sometimes it helps to work this things out on paper. Draw your array, then think: How would a human do it? If you can come up with a clear algorithm that way and wrap your head around it, then it will become straightforward to translate it to Java (or whatever language).

Comment: I tried using the linked code, however it did not work for me. It only did the same amount my code did (up until the major diagonal) and then gave me an index out of bounds exception. I tried writing it out but it ends up going back into the diagonals I have already done. Just curious as to if you have any other hints (I don't expect you to write my code, but I would really appreciate anything)

Comment: You get an index out of bounds exception if you try to access an index that is out of bounds. The way to stop this exception is to *not* access indexes that are out of bounds. So, do bounds checking if you have to, or otherwise modify your logic so that never happens.

Answer (score 0):

For calculating the remaining part of the matrix you can insert two nested for loops below your code. Something like this-

```
    sum = 0;
    int t,k;
    int result[] = new int[20];
    for(c = 1; c <= 7; c++) {
        t = c;
        for(i = 7; i >= c; i--) {
            sum += board[i][t];
            t++;
        }
        result[k] = sum;    // result[k] will store each diagonal sum
        k++;
        sum = 0;
    }
```